# How to change the legend / label names on the pie chart in plotly express

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, visualization, plotly-express

Shown below is the syntax used to change the legend / label names on plotly express

```
fig = px.pie(df,
             values = "Total",
             names = 'index',
             hole = 0.5,
             color_discrete_sequence = ['#2C3E50','#CACFD2'],
             labels = {1:'yes', 2:'no'} )
        
fig.update_traces(textinfo='value + percent')
fig.show()
```

However, the label names does not change as it shows as below

[image]

How can I change the legend / label names on the pie chart in plotly express as ***1 should be "Yes" and 2 should be "No"***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the names of the values on `index` with `map` and then plot it:

```
labels = {1:'yes', 2:'no'}
df['index'] = df['index'].map(labels)
fig = px.pie(...)
```

Comment: `names` accepts Series, so it is also possible to pass the modified column directly to `pie` _e.g._ `fig = px.pie(df, values="Total", names=df['index'].map({1: 'yes', 2: 'no'}), ...)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.